# What kind of class structure do I need?

Tags: c++

I just needed something like this:

I have got a robot class which contains a motor object and a predefined callback function (which is triggered on an interrupt).

robot.h

```
class robot
{
public:
    motor motor1;
};
```

motor.h

```
class motor
{
public:
   int incrementPosition();
   int getPosition();
private:
    int position;
};
```

callback.cpp

```
void callback(){
   motor1.incrementPosition(); //callback function needs to reach this already created motor1
}
```

What I am trying to achive is:

- Robot and motor objects has to be created only once (only one robot and one motor are allowable, bacause it is connected to a real physical robot and a motor),
- Motor object (`motor1`) has to be created automatically and most importantly, it should be callable from the prefined `callback` function.

So the main should be like this,

```
main(){
   robot myRobot;
   robot myRobot2; //is not allowed or should be useless

   printf("%d\n", myRobot.motor1.getPosition());
}
```

Comment: Can you install any user parameters for the callback function?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern) may help.

Comment: Maybe you could write some sort of "GetOrCreate" function? Should the `robot` be managed by anything?

Comment: I can not install any user parameters for the callback function. I can only use global variables/object in 'callback'.
Singleton only solves (as I understood), "object has to be created once" problem. How will I react that 'motor' object from 'callback'?

Comment: @DreamsOfElectricSheep, I am not sure I understood, what do you mean by "robot be managed by anything"?

Comment: *" I can only use global variables/object in 'callback'"* - Sorry to tell you, but the framwork you are working with is either c*ap, or you are abusing it.

Comment: Yes. `callback` is a `__weak void` function defined in another **.c** file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not that I really like to recommend that<sup>1</sup>, but obviously the [*Singleton Pattern*](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton) comes to mind:

```
class robot {
    robot() {}
public:
    motor motor1;
    static robot& instance() {
        static robot theRobot;
        return theRobot;
    }
};
```

The only way to access an instance of `robot` is to use the `instance()` function then.

```
main(){
   robot myRobot; // Fails to compile since the constructor is private

   printf("%d\n", robot::instance().motor1.getPosition());
               // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Access the one and only instance 
}
```

The same way the single `motor` instance can be accessed in the callback function:

```
void callback(){
   robot::instance().motor1.incrementPosition();
}
```

---

Some more considerations:

- Make your `robot` class implement an interface like

  ```
   struct IRobot {
       virtual ~IRobot() {}
       virtual std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IMotor>>& motors() = 0;
   };
  ```

  this makes it easier to write isolated unit tests and mock the `robot` singleton.
- Instead of the `static` `instance()` function provide a global access function for the singleton instance that returns the above mentioned interface. This also can be easier replaced with a function that returns a mock object for unit testing.

---

<sup>1)</sup><sub>The *Singleton Design Pattern* is often blamed as a bad design, and in most cases it actually is a bad decision. Nevertheless there are valid use cases, especially when designing embedded systems. You have one single and autonomous robot, that's clear and deserves a singleton.

It's considerable though, if you should fix yourself to a single motor from the beginning, it would be hard to change if the HW engineers decide to need a second motor.</sub>